# How to get an array of numeric intervals given a specifoc set of numbers

Tags: google-sheets

In Google Sheets I have a situation like this 
[image]

In the first row I have a sequence of four numbers:
The first number indicates a minimum amount of an interval.
The second number indicates a maximum amount of that same interval.
The third number indicates how many times the interval repeats
The fourth number indicates the gap between each interval.
In range `A4:B6` I see the result I want to get, meaning:
3 intervals, separated by the specified gap.
The formula to get this array should be placed in cell `A4`

Is there a way to achieve this?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SEQUENCE()` with `HSTACK()` function.

```
=HSTACK(SEQUENCE(C1,1,A1,D1),SEQUENCE(C1,1,B1,D1))
```

[image]